# react-scripts build same build inside build

Tags: reactjs, build, duplicates, react-scripts

When I build react app in linux, it generate build successfully, but inside build, I can find there is another build and the content is exactly same.
I tried it after removing build, but it generate same build inside buil
I am using "react": "^18.2.0", and I didn't set any build setting in package.json

[image]

When I run it on windows PC, it doesn't create another build.
It only happened in linux.